# OpenDMK/SNMP -> How to access to a MIB objects?

Tags: java, server, snmp

I just want to know how can i access to a SnmpMib object. For example, I have defined GEOGESTOR-MIB. I setup a SNMP Server (SNMP Adaptor) and I can access to any object of the MIB easily via MIB BROWSER and here is my problem:

- I'm running a customized APP server.
- I have some variables to monitorize:
   *Number of clients connected.
   *A table with:
       -Client IP.
       -etc...(not interesting)

For example, each time a client connects, I would want to increment the object of the MIB "clientsNum". My question is: how can I access to these objects? I leave over here the code:

```
public class Snmp implements SnmpInterfaz {
// Atributos gestionables
private int numClientes = 0;

public Snmp() {
    GEOGESTOR_MIB mib = new GEOGESTOR_MIB();
    int port = 5001;
    SnmpAdaptorServer snmpAdaptor = new SnmpAdaptorServer(port);

      try {
            // The agent is started on a non standard SNMP port: 8085

            // Start the adaptor
            snmpAdaptor.start();

            // Send a coldStart SNMP Trap
            snmpAdaptor.snmpV1Trap(0, 0, null);

            // Create the MIB you want in the agent (ours is MIB-II subset)
            // Initialize the MIB so it creates the associated MBeans
            mib.init();

            // Bind the MIB to the SNMP adaptor
            mib.setSnmpAdaptor(snmpAdaptor);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public void aumentaClientes(){
    this.numClientes++;
}

public void decrementaClientes(){
    this.numClientes--;
}

public int getNumClientes(){
    return this.numClientes;
}
```

}

I want a way for changing "mib" objects.

PD: Sorry for my English.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you seeing?  You might get better answers if you give more information about your own efforts.  See [ask]